# Is obtaining multiple followers in Skyrim through console commands permanent?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've recently begun modding my skyrim, and I've decided that I would like to try out having multiple followers. Unfortunately, the three multiple follower mods: AFT, UFO, and EFF, don't seem to operate through the SkyUI MCM menu, making customization really laborious and difficult.

This has led me to wonder if altering my follower count via the `set playerfollowercount to <#>` command is permanent, allowing me to simply have more followers. I'm assuming that if I set it to 4 or something, I will be able to have up to 4 followers at once. My question is if this command persists through saves and is permanent. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is permanent**

A friend has informed me that console commands that 'set' something are permanent, while commands that 'mod' something are not. I haven't been able to find anything either denying or confirming this, but it makes sense, as commands like `set playerlevel` have to be permanent, otherwise it would be entirely useless.

Unfortunately, I have discovered that the console command does not increase your follower count. Apparently, all it can be used for is to reset it (aka, 0) in order to fix several follower related bugs. Entering `set playerfollowercount to 4` or something similar simply keeps your current follower and removes the dialogue option to recruit any others. It appears that a mod is required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it persists through saves.
You can however always return to the original value through console commands as well as dismiss followers.

Comment: So this is weird. I have duly inserted the console command. It looks like it accepted it fine, though there was no additional text whatsoever. Now however, I can't seem to recruit, because there is no longer any dialogue option to do so. Lydia is still following me fine, but the option to recruit additional people is simply gone. ... What have I done?!?

Comment: Try setting it back to zero

Comment: Setting it back to zero did not clear Lydia (she was still following me), but did restore the dialogue to recruit Uthgerd. Once I did however, Lydia left me. I set the count back to 4, but now the dialogue option is gone again and I'm stuck with Uthgerd. Hmm.... I'm wondering if there's a command to manually add a follower. I don't see one.

Comment: Ah... I found someone else with the same problem. Looks like Skyrim is hard-coded that way, leaving mods as the only option. That makes me wonder what on earth the command is even for; just setting it to 0?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, as far as I know "set" commands persist. I think the issue with "playerfollowercount" is that it sets the number you have rather than setting how many you can have. I know that's how "animalfollowercount" works because a modder stated in their mod description that dismissing one of their animal followers would set that number back to 0 and would allow you to recruit another.